# Radius of convergence of complex $\log$ around $\exp(\frac{3\pi i}{4})$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $\log: \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty;0] \to \mathbb{C}$. I am asked to calculate the radius of convergence of the power series of $\log$ around $z_0=\exp(\frac{3\pi i}{4})$.

Reading this question: [Radius of convergence of power series of complex $\log$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292514/radius-of-convergence-of-power-series-of-complex-log/1293808#1293808), I know that the radius of convergence $R$ has to be $R=1$.

In class I learned the "trick" that the radius of convergence of a power series can easily be calculated by looking at the distance between the development point $z_0$ and the nearest singularity.

This leads to my question why $R$ is not given by $R=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, since $\exp({\frac{3\pi i}{4}}) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and therefore $\operatorname{dist}(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};(-\infty, 0]) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Why does the "distance"-argument fail here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest singularity is $0$, not the whole ray $(-\infty,0]$. And the distance from $\exp\left(\frac{3\pi i}4\right)$ to $0$ is $1$ indeed.

You seem to think that “singularity” is the same thing as “point outside the domain of $f$”. If, say, I define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\frac{\sin z}z,\end{array}$$then $0$ doesn't belong to the domain of $f$. However, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ centered at any point $z_0$ of $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is $\infty$, rather than $|z_0|$. In this case, $0$ is a removable singularity.

However, in the case of $\log$, $0$ is *not* a removable singularity, since $\lim_{z\to0}|\log z|=\infty$. But this argument doesn't apply to $z_0\in(-\infty,0)$; near $z_0$, there is an analytic branch of the logarithm: let $\omega$ be any logarithm of $z_0$ and consider the power series $\omega+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nz_0^{\,n}}(z-z_0)^n$.

Comment: Why is the nearest singularity $0$? $\log$ is not defined on $(-\infty, 0]$ and not only at $0$.

Comment: I've added another paragraph to my answer. Is everything clear now?

Comment: Not really to be honest. I understand the case you described in your example when we have a removable singularity. Are $(-\infty,0)$ all removable singularities of $\log$? How do you know that $z=0$ is the nearest singularity of $\log$?

Comment: I've added another paragraph to my answer.